# ASP.NET dropdown ListItem text showing incorrectly when using multiple dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Goal**: I have 3 dropdowns for 3 different people.

I would like to be able to update the database with value from dropdown that is used. I would like to be able to use more than one dropdown without having to manually refresh the page. It's on `Site.Master` so they appear on every page.

**Problem**: the value in the database updates correctly after the update, but the text in the dropdown becomes incorrect if I use more than one dropdown without refreshing the page.

It works fine if user makes a change on first dropdown, then goes to another page, then uses the second dropdown. BUT the view acts strange if I

- Change Dropdown1 (e.g. from True to False).
- Then change Dropdown2 (True to False).

At this point, dropdown 1 will show True again (even though it was changed to False a couple steps ago).

It's almost as if the first dropdown gets the current value from the second dropdown.

However, if I refresh the page, it shows the appropriate values (and the database has the correct value the entire time)

Probably easier with screenshots:

**After** changing Professor1 from True to False (OK):

[image: Professor1]

**After** changing Professor2 from True to False (NOT OK - notice Professor 1 appears as True again, even though its correct in the DB):

[image: dropdowns]

What I've tried:

- I've used debug breakpoints on every line in the C# I could think of
- I've tried moving the code into the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method
- I've tried changing from `.Text` to `.SelectedValue`
- I've tried using multiple `OnSelectedIndexChanged` methods instead of one

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" height="20" width="20" 
        CssClass="professoricon"/>
    <sup><asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" 
        CssClass="oval"/></sup> 
    <asp:Label ID="myLabelMid" runat="server" CssClass="professorname"/> 
    <asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddlAvailability1" 
        AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAvailability_OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
        CssClass="dropdowns">
        <asp:ListItem ID="LT1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem ID="RT1"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropdownList>             
</div>
            
<asp:Panel ID="row2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" CssClass="professoricon"/>
    <sup><asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server" Font-Size="20px"
        CssClass="oval"/></sup> <asp:Label ID="M2" runat="server" 
        CssClass="professorname"/> 
    <asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddlAvailability2" 
        AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAvailability2_OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
        CssClass="dropdowns">
        <asp:ListItem ID="LT2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem ID="RT2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropdownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

**C#**:

```
PageLoad() {
    myLabel.Text = professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[0].NumberOfActiveVisits.ToString();
    myLabelMid.Text = professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[0].LastName.ToString();
    LT1.Text = professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[0].Available.ToString();
    RT1.Text = (!professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[0].Available).ToString();
    
    if (professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList.Count>1)
    {
        L2.Text = professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[1].NumberOfActiveVisits.ToString();
        M2.Text = professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[1].LastName.ToString();
        LT2.Text = professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[1].Available.ToString();
        RT2.Text = (!professorStatsListDto.professorStatsList[1].Available).ToString();
        row2.Visible = true;                
    }               
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't change items' text. Try setting SelectedIndex of DropdownList to 0 or 1.

Comment: What is professorStatsListDto?

Comment: Placing my code inside a if(!Page.IsPostback) seems to have resolved this